# using directive in header file

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a class that I need to convert to a template class. For this, I am moving the implementation from class.cpp to class-in.h that will then be included at the end of class.h.

The implementation has a few `using ...` directives as well as a gflag `DEFINE_bool`. I need to use these in the class-inl.h file but I am told that they shouldn't be placed in a header file.
The class-inl.h is a header file but it will never be included as a regular header file.

Is there a way I can get rid of using/ gflag in the header file? Can I put the gflag, using statements in a class.cpp?

edit: I meant using declaration example `using std::cout`

Comment: _"I am seeing warnings that I can't in a header file."_ Please, [edit] your question to include the warnings you are trying to solve.

Comment: removed the bit about warnings

Comment: "*I am told that they shouldn't be placed in a header file*" - told by whom? "*Is there a way I can get rid of using/ gflag in the header file?*" - It would really help to see a [mcve] of the code you are having trouble with. Then someone can give you a more definitive answer explaining how to make it work

Comment: Are you referring to [using-directives](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace), [using-declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration), or [type aliases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)?  Only the first two should be avoided in header files, and even then only if they are used in a way that "leaks" outside of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to not put `using`s into header files if they are only used for implementation. They unnecessarily leak symbols and implementation details. If you define `using my_shortcut_for_long_type=....`, someone is bound to start using it and code breaks when you decide to change it.

It won't kill you to write `std::cout` instead of `cout`. If you want to shorten a long type, place the using into e.g. `impl` namespace; same goes for what used to be static functions in .cpps. Do not forget to mark them `inline` if you decide to define them also in the header. `using` can also be defined inside function scope, use that too.

Definitely do not put `using namespace std;` or any other namespace into headers files unless that is the purpose of that header.

Refrain from using macros if possible also.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally fine to place `using`  in a header file.

> Is there a way I can get rid of using ... in the header file?

Yes: Don't depend on the declaration in the header, then you don't need to declare it. But as I stated, there is generally no need to do get rid of `using` in a header.

> Is there a way I can get rid of ... gflag in the header file?

Define it in a source file instead.